# Populate checkboxgroup

Tags: database, extjs, checkboxlist, populate

I need populate a checkboxgroup from db.
I have a method #populateObrasSociales(anArrayOfChkbox), the code of this method is:

```
populateObrasSociales: function(anArrayOfChkBox){
        var chkGrp = Ext.create('Ext.form.CheckboxGroup',{
            columns: 1,
            vertical: true,
            items: anArrayOfChkBox
        });
}
```

anArrayOfCheckBox is:

> ["{name:IOMA,boxLabel:IOMA,inputValue:1}",
>   "{name:OSPE,boxLabel:OSPE,inputValue:2}"]

When, shows the form FireBug says:

> TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

Any ideas ?. Thanks !.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the fact that your checkbox config objects are strings doesn't help:

```
["{name:IOMA,boxLabel:IOMA,inputValue:1}", "{name:OSPE,boxLabel:OSPE,inputValue:2}"]
```

Without the quotes, they're objects:

```
[{name:IOMA,boxLabel:IOMA,inputValue:1}, {name:OSPE,boxLabel:OSPE,inputValue:2}]
```